# HTML Frame Force New Window in all Links

Tags: html, frameset

I have frames setup on a page, is there a way to force all links in a child frame to open in a new window('blank') rather than 'self'?

I have no access to the page that I have in my frame, sometimes the links open new pages sometimes they just transfer to a totally new page.  I want to keep some consistency by making all links open in new pages.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some javascript:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; ++i) {
    links[i].target = '_blank';
}
```

You'll just have to get a reference to the document in your frame (sorry, it's been a long time since I've worked with frames). From memory it's something easy like `frame.document`

I'm not positive that you can modify the DOM of external pages, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; ++i) {
    links[i].target = '_blank';
}
```

This will not work for Frames loaded by Javascript to open in a new Window :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use frames.

Or load them in using a HTTP object (there's plenty in a lot of server-side languages), modify the links using regular expressions to point to '_blank' instead' and then put them on your page.

Alternatively, you *might* be able to use the DOM:

```
nodeLink = document.getElementById("alink");
nodeLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

What am I missing when I respond with the following?

If you can't change the page in the frame, you're not going to change its behavior.

Comment: I was just asking if there was some way I could use javascript to manipulate the frame and what/how it is loaded.

Comment: Got it.  nickf's solution is good, but I do believe you're *not* able to "modify the DOM of external pages".  Hence my comment about "you can't change the page in the frame", as you don't own it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Just replace `_blank` with whatever target you want to be the base for all links on the page.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp